# How can I drop duplicate with similar strings

Tags: python, pandas

The problem is that there are some some titles where there is a minor difference some have color difference some have space some other things but there is not a similar trend in the differences. The rest of the details are matching in every column for the titles.

Example below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'title': ["Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max (256GB) - Gold",
              "Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max (256GB) - Pacific Blue",
              "boAt Bassheads 100 in Ear Wired Earphones with Mic(Black)",
              "boAt Bassheads 100 in Ear Wired Earphones with Mic(Furious Red)",
              "boAt Bassheads 100 in Ear Wired Earphones with Mic(White)",
              "Redmi 9A Sport (Carbon Black, 3GB RAM, 32GB Storage) | 2GHz Octa-core Helio G25 Processor | 5000 mAh Battery",
              "Redmi 9A Sport (Coral Green, 3GB RAM, 32GB Storage) | 2GHz Octa-core Helio G25 Processor | 5000 mAh Battery"
 ],
    
    'List_Price':[129900, 129900, 299, 299, 299,8299,8299],
    'Total_Ratings':[1536, 1536, 313053, 313053, 313053,155678,155678],
     'Stars':[4.7, 4.7, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1,4.2,4.2]
  
})
```

Note: This is just an example, There are lot of titles that have a minor difference.

I want something like this. Output:

1. Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max (256GB)
2. boAt Bassheads 100 in Ear Wired Earphones with Mic
3. Redmi 9A Sport (Carbon Black, 3GB RAM, 32GB Storage) | 2GHz Octa-core Helio G25 Processor | 5000 mAh Battery

with all the other column records as they are.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to that, since the data you wan't to filter has different properties.

A naive but effective approach would be to apply split on specific characters to remove some text.

Another approach would be to use regex to remove whatever is within parenthesis.

After that you can just drop duplicates

Here is an example:

```
def function_1 (text, term):
    try:
        return text.split('{}'.format(term))[0].strip()
    except:
        return text

df['title'] = df.apply(lambda row: function_1(row['title'],'-'),1)
df['title'] = df.apply(lambda row: function_1(row['title'],'|'),1)

df['title'] = df.apply(lambda row: re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', row['title']).strip(),1)

df = df.drop_duplicates()

df.head()
```

[image]